# Mixin overriding in Extjs

Tags: extjs, mixins

There are mixin class that merges methods to target class. I want to know when merging process starts?

I've overridden one of the methods of mixin, but it hasn't been overrode in target class. So I assume that merging goes before overriding.

```
Ext.define('Ext.container.DockingContainer',
...
Ext.define('Ext.panel.Panel',
...
Ext.override(Ext.container.DockingContainer
```

At first ext.js defines mixin, then target class. When I override mixins method, it doesn't impact target classes method. So how to solve this problem? How to override mixins method properly?

Comment: By that point it's too late, you would need to override it before the mixin is applied. As it goes, `DockingContainer` is only used in that one instance, so you can just override panel itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've overridden it with this way:

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.container.DockingContainer', 
{    
    override: 'Ext.container.DockingContainer',
    getDockedItems: function(selector, beforeBody) 
    {
          ....
    }
}, function() {
        Ext.Object.each(Ext.ClassManager.classes, function(name, cls) {
            if (cls.prototype && cls.prototype.mixins && cls.prototype.mixins.hasOwnProperty("docking")) {
                cls.prototype.getDockedItems = this.prototype.getDockedItems;
            }
        }, this);
    }
);
```